# ¿Porque estoy recibiendo muchos errores en la consola la hacer click en un boton de login en twitter?

Tags: php, javascript

En mi trabajo me mandaron a revisar cual es la razon, de que en la consola aparecen muchos errores al hacer click en el boton de login de twitter.
El boton ejecuta el siguiente codigo jvascript

```
function twitterLogin(){ setTimeout(function () { loading(); window.location="http://192.168.1.102/islamiqa-project/hauth.done%3DTwitter?to=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.102%2Fislamiqa-project%2Fhomepage" }, 100);}
```

y recibo los siguientes mensajes de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay algún parámetro que pueda enviar junto la url que me evite estos errores en la consola?

Porque se producen estos errores? aclaro que no entiendo muy bien lo de la api de twitter, he leido parte de la documentación pero hay poca información acerca de errores y el método que explican difiere de lo que aqui muestro.

Answer (score 0):

De lo que he leído es un problema con CSP(Política de Seguridad de Contenido) no precisamente con la API de twitter, has agregado un metatag con la información de CSP, sino prueba con esto:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data:" />
```

Lo tomé de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593548/csp-refused-api-twitter). Aquí puedes encontrar información adicional de la [Política de Seguridad de Contenido](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/?hl=es)

Comment: Hola, acabo de probar colocando el meta desde la pagina en donde ejecuto el boton y aún sigo teniendo los errores en la consola. Leyendo lo que me pasaste me parece que ya es un problema de la pagina de autenticacion de twitter y son ellos lo que tienen que agregar esa etiqueta, o estoy equvocado? de antemano muchas gracias